# Distribute Crystal Report to Employees

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to distribute crystal reports to my employees but ensure security. Are there any alternatives to Crystal Report Server?

Technical requirements are:

Able to publish reports on Web - Intranet
active directory intergrated
Crystal Reports 11
SQL Server 2008/2012
Email compliant 
Schedule able
HTML email - able to add images, etc to scheduled emails
API

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want to write your own solution or simply buy something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to distribute the reports or you need to give the employees access to reports? In case you want just to distribute the reports (I guess you will do this by e-mail) you might check the schedulers available on the market - the prices are in the range of $300-$800. If you want to allow users to run the reports in a local network you can use a desktop report viewer - prices start at $25 per seat with discounts for quantity. For example 25 seats will cost you around $400, unlimited seats  - $1000. There are solutions which will allow you to access the reports on the Web. The prices start at $5000 per server. Which of these options will work for you ?